# Como fazer lógica de habilitar campo de texto por vez quando preenchido

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Como devo proceder com a lógica?

Ha um Formulário de cadastro de dados na página, à saber:

- Nome
- Sobrenome
- Idade
- Celular

Preciso deixar estes campos da seguinte forma:

1- Quando a página for carregada o campo **Sobrenome**, **Idade** e **Celular** deveram estar desabilitado

2- Quando **clicar** e **preencher** o próximo campo abaixo deverá ficar habilitado

3- E assim por diante, para os demais, sendo sucessivamente

Por fim, quando todos os campos forem preenchidos aparecerá o botão `submit`.

> **NOTA** - *Quando o formulário receber o evento `submit` voltam agora todos os campos [nome, sobrenome, idade e celular] a ficar inacessíveis.*

---

**Pra se ter uma Idéia introdutória**

```js
function Inibe() {
  document.formulario.T1.disabled = true;
}

function Exibe() {
  document.formulario.T1.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario">
<p align="center">
<input type="text" name="T1" size="20" onload="Inibe()"></p>
<p align="center">
&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
<input type="radio" name="a" onClick="Exibe()" value="1">Habilita</p>
<p align="center">
<input type="radio" name="a" onClick="Inibe()" value="2" checked>Desabilita</p>
<p align="center">
&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Uma das forma de se fazer isso seria: 1) definir a quantidade mínima de caracteres para cada campo 2) contar os caracteres no momento em que forem digitados 3) Se a quantidade for igual ou superior habilita o próximo campo, do contrário não. Linguagens: javascript ou jquery

Comment: @WilsonRosaGomes Então Wilson, o meio de validar a quantidade de caracteres dentro de cada campo ja possuo em Javascript! Agora, se por ventura tiver um exemplo prático neste segmento poderia postar como resposta por gentileza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o JQuery você pode fazer desta forma (acompanhe os comentários):

```js
$($("input").on("change input paste", function(){ //Event handle para quando o usuario escrever algo
    if ($(this).val()){ //Checa se tem valor (truthy)
        let atual = $(this).data("order") //Pega a ordem do input
        $('input[data-order="' + (atual + 1) + '"]').removeAttr("disabled") //Remove o atributo disabled do prox input
    }
    else{
     $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true) //Adiciona disable ao botão
    }
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return false">
<input data-order="1" placeholder="nome">
<input data-order="2" placeholder="sobrenome" disabled>
<input data-order="3" placeholder="idade" disabled>
<input data-order="4" placeholder="celular" disabled>
<input data-order="5" type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e0d2tje/18/).

Agora com o Javascript puro, usando ES6, você pode fazer desta forma:

```js
changed = (input) => {
    if (input.value){ //Checa se tem valor (truthy)
        let atual = parseInt(input.getAttribute("data-order")) //Pega a ordem do input
        document.querySelector('input[data-order="' + (atual + 1) + '"]').removeAttribute("disabled") //Remove o atributo disabled do prox input
    }
    else{    document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").setAttribute("disabled", true) //Adiciona disable ao botão
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
<input data-order="1" onchange="changed(this)" oninput="changed(this)" placeholder="nome">
<input data-order="2" onchange="changed(this)" oninput="changed(this)" placeholder="sobrenome" disabled>
<input data-order="3" onchange="changed(this)" oninput="changed(this)" placeholder="idade" disabled>
<input data-order="4" onchange="changed(this)" oninput="changed(this)" placeholder="celular" disabled>
<input data-order="5" type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Ficaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/a4tmj2d4/4/

Comment: Não precisa colocar `document.querySelector('input[data-order="' + (atual + 1) + '"]')`, basta colocar `input.nextElementSibling`

Answer (score 2):

Habilita campo de texto por vez quando preenchido, e desabilita os subsequentes quando limpa um campo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.step').on("change input paste", function() {
    next_step = $(this).next('.step');
    all_next_steps = $(this).nextAll('.step');
    // Se o elemento tiver um valor
    if ($(this).val()) {
        // deve também realizar a validação aqui
        next_step.attr('disabled', false);
    }
    // Se o elemento não tiver um valor ou for apagado
    else {
        // limpa o valor de todas as próximas etapas e adiciona disable
        all_next_steps.val('');
        all_next_steps.attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  $("#habilita").click(function (){
       // habilita o primeiro campo 
        $("#step1").prop("disabled", false);

    });

    $("#desabilita").click(function (){
       // desabilita e limpa  tudo 
        $('input[id^="step"]').val(''); 
        $('input[id^="step"]').prop("disabled", true);
        
        /******BONUS******/
        $('#step6').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#step6').val('');
        /****************/
 

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="formulario">
    <!-- Comece apenas com o primeiro habilitado -->
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step1" name="T1" disabled/>
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step2" disabled />
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step3" disabled />
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step4" disabled />
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step5" disabled />
    
    <!--*******Bonus********-->
    <select id="step6" class="step" data-id="cazzo" disabled>
        <option value="">Escolha um</option>
        <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
        <option value="Francisco">Francisco</option>
    </select>
    <!--*******************-->
    

<input type="radio" name="a" value="1" id="habilita">Habilita
<input type="radio" name="a" id="desabilita" checked>Desabilita

</form>
```

Caso queira validar também a quantidade de caracteres nos inputs

troque essa linha

`if ($(this).val()) {`

por essa

`if (($(this).val())&&($(this).val()).length>3) {`

> `length>3` significa quantidade de caracteres acima de 3

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.step').on("change input paste", function() {
    next_step = $(this).next('.step');
    all_next_steps = $(this).nextAll('.step');

    if (($(this).val())&&($(this).val()).length>3) {
        next_step.attr('disabled', false);
    }
    // Se o elemento não tiver um valor ou for apagado
    else {
        all_next_steps.val('');
        all_next_steps.attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  $("#habilita").click(function (){
        $("#step1").prop("disabled", false);
    });

    $("#desabilita").click(function (){
        $('input[id^="step"]').val(''); 
        $('input[id^="step"]').prop("disabled", true);
        
        /******BONUS******/
        $('#step6').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#step6').val('');
        /****************/
 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="formulario">
    <!-- Comece apenas com o primeiro habilitado -->
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step1" name="T1" disabled/>
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step2" disabled />
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step3" disabled />
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step4" disabled />
    <input type="text" class="step" id="step5" disabled />
    
    <!--*******Bonus********-->
    <select id="step6" class="step" data-id="cazzo" disabled>
        <option value="">Escolha um</option>
        <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
        <option value="Francisco">Francisco</option>
    </select>
    <!--*******************-->

<input type="radio" name="a" value="1" id="habilita">Habilita
<input type="radio" name="a" id="desabilita" checked>Desabilita

</form>
```